# Erro em fazer upload ionic app

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic2

quando passo o comando no meu terminal ionic upload
apresenta o erro abaixo e nao sobe o arquivo no ionic view

```
ionic upload
Uploading app...

An error occurred uploading the build: An error occurred uploading your application - App ID 348ffe7e does not ex
ist

An error occurred uploading your application - App ID 348ffe7e does not exist (CLI v2.2.1)

Your system information:

 ordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.9.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Como faço para resolver isso?

Comment: estranho que a primeira vez ele subiu normalmente, ja na segunda nao funcionou e nao foi alterado nada em nenhun arquivo de config

Comment: Editei a pergunta e removi a tag ionic, que hoje nada tem a ver com ionic2. Qualquer coisa, caso seja ao contrário, adicione novamente removendo a outra tag. abs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso não tenha enviado nenhuma vez sua aplicação para simulação, abaixo segue os passos que deve resolver seu problema:

1. Abra o arquivo `ionic.project.json` que está na raiz do seu projeto
2. Altere seu `app_id` para vazio (delete o existente)
3. Tente fazer upload novamente com `ionic upload`

Caso você já exista o App ID cadastrado no seu perfil, logo já foi simulado uma ou mais vezes, execute os comandos abaixo:

```
# ionic io init
# ionic upload
```

Veja na documentação mais [detalhes de configuração](https://docs.ionic.io/setup.html).

Comment: Otima solução funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado